# echo hyperlinks in array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have an array that looks like this:

```
   [6625] => Trump class="mediatype"> href="/news/picture">Slideshow: [6628] => href="http://www.example.com/news/picture/god=USRTX1N84J">GOP [6630] => nation
```

I need to be able to pull out anything within href="" of the array and put into a new one.

I have tried:

```
      <?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
$arr = explode(" ",$homepage);


function getStringInBetween($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " " . $string;
    $initial = strpos($string, $start);

    if ($initial == 0) return "";

    $initial += strlen($start);
    $length = strpos($string, $end, $initial) - $initial;

    return substr($string, $initial, $length);
}

echo getStringInBetween($arr[0], 'href="', '"')
?>
```

Comment: Is the `href=""`'s in an array?

Comment: yes as you can see above array example entry 6625 includes href="/news/picture"> and array entry 6628 includes href="http://www.example.com/news/picture/god=USRTX1N84J"  ....so need to take those out and have a new array, being that you know what going on, ill tell you the new array is going to be posted into mysql db

Comment: Added answer, is that it?

Comment: @Script47 please advise your getStringInBetween how can use the & symbol in the last segment? for example getStringInBetween($val, 'href="', '&')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, adapt it to suit you,

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
$arr = explode(" ",$homepage);

function getStringInBetween($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " " . $string;
    $initial = strpos($string, $start);

    if ($initial == 0) return "";

    $initial += strlen($start);
    $length = strpos($string, $end, $initial) - $initial;

    return substr($string, $initial, $length);
}

foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if (strpos($val, 'href') !== false) {
        echo getStringInBetween($val, 'href="', '"');
    }
}
?>
```

This example when ran outputted `google.com/hello`.

Comment: Updated the code, all you had to was change it to `getStringInBetween($arr[0], 'href="', '"')`.

Comment: its returning empty.. updated my code to display what is being used.

Comment: @PlacePrintApp does key 0 actually exist? If it doesn't, then add a loop to it then in the loop use the function.

Comment: key 0 exists but it is not a href="".....so put the function inside 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { } ?

Comment: @PlacePrintApp if it isn't `href=""` what is it?

Comment: Array ( [0] => welcome but  [6625] => Trump class="mediatype"> href="/news/picture"..... so there are href=""

Comment: @PlacePrintApp Give me a few minutes.

Comment: how can i do echo getStringInBetween($val, 'href="', '&ss');  ...the & at the end causes parse error

Comment: using your getStringInBetween how can use the & symbol in the last segment?